# Sub Navigation Menu Disappeared and Font not working

Tags: css

I am currently designing a site and I dont know what I did but my sub menu wont show anymore. When I Inspect Element via Chrome, I see all of the pages listed there but it wont show on the actual site.

URL: http://envisionmediallc.com/prodigy/

Sub menu should be showing under the About page.

Also, I installed a font and added it to the navigation bar an headings. It worked great for a couple days and now the font will only work on the homepage but no other pages. I cant figure it out!

Comment: Can you post some of the html/css that demonstrates what you have done so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u most change this css code :

```
.nav-primary {overflow: hidden;}
```

to this :

```
.nav-primary {overflow: visible;}
```

so when ur menu height is more than  height will shown.

for showing fonts in every page u most use the stylesheet.css in every page.
u llinked the stylesheet in every page but ur address is wrong. 
for correcting this please change  :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">
```

to this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://envisionmediallc.com/prodigy/stylesheet.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">
```

or :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="(ur directory)/stylesheet.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">
```

so ur style will be load in this page.

Comment: I cant till I have more reputation :(